# Get full date and time value from a cell in Excel with NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I am trying to get data from Excel files (the old xls ones) and in particular, one column is formatted as date though it should be formatted as time.

When I read the file with NPOI, I get only the date part of the cell; the time part is fixed to 12PM.

When I open the file in Excel and click the cell, I can see that the time is populated.

For example, in Excel, the cell's "formula value" is:

```
4/23/2020  3:00:00 PM
```

And the cell is formatted as:

```
4/23/2020
```

When I read the cell with NPOI, I get:

```
var value = cell.NumericCellValue;// value = 43944.5
var dateValue = DateUtil.GetJavaDate(cell.NumericCellValue);// dateValue = {4/23/2020 12:00:00 PM}
var formattedValue = _formatter.FormatCellValue(cell);// formattedValue = "4/23/20"
var formula = cell.CellFormula;// throws exception "Cannot get a formula value from a numeric formula cell"
```

I read the code for `DateUtil.GetJavaDate` and `43944.5` does indeed convert to `4/23/2020 12:00:00 PM` which means that `NumericCellValue` is the value with formatting applied already.

So my question is: how can I get the `4/23/2020  3:00:00 PM` "formula value" for that cell using NPOI?

If you have suggestions with other libraries, I'm happy to try them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `DateCellValue` property of the cell:

```
if (cell.CellType == CellType.Numeric && DateUtil.IsCellDateFormatted(cell))
{
    DateTime date = cell.DateCellValue;
    Debug.WriteLine(date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"));
}
```

Comment: That gives me the same value: it's using NumericCellValue internally. I inspected all of the cell's properties and private members in debug and I couldn't find anything that would give me the raw value. I'm guessing it's not loaded at all in the cell object and I would need to query it from the sheet or workbook in another way.

Comment: OK, it worked for me, but then I don't have your same workbooks.  Sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: You're right... I was looking at the wrong cell, I feel dumb!

Comment: Don't sweat it; it happens to us all sometimes.  I'm glad you were able to get it working.